# How to skip jQuery.validity validation for selected input buttons?

Tags: php, jquery, validity.js

I'm using [jQuery.validity](http://validity.thatscaptaintoyou.com/) to validate PHP form inputs. I need to skip validation when user clicked selected input button (eg: Logout button)

Sample code used for validation:

```
$("form").validity(function() {
    $("#DateInput") 
        .require()
        .match("date");
});
```

How to skip validation for selected input buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted this question in [Validity official site, issues section](http://code.google.com/p/validity/issues/list). This is the [answer](http://code.google.com/p/validity/issues/detail?id=64) given

> In general, validation is bound to a form rather than a submit button.
>   If your logout button is in a form you don't want to validate, just
>   don't call validity on that form. e.g.
>   $("#formWithInputs").validity(...)

So managed to make it work by locating input controls in different forms

Answer (score 0):

make change the logout button to `<input id="logout" type="button" />` instead of submit

Comment: add $('logout').click(function(){...}) on the logout.